# Suggestions for mobile (phonegap) auto update?

Tags: xml, mobile, cordova

I need a little advice re. building a recipe app for mobile. Using Jquery mobile, and PhoneGap to build the app... one of the requirements is that the recipes can be updated from outside the app. So I'll need to check for, and download the updated XML, and also each recipe has images tied to it, and the images should be downloaded as well. There's even some chance images already downloaded can be updated.
What is a good approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Connection API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection) to detect when your app is being used and when there is a good connection available. Then you can fetch the updated data, including images, from the server. You can probably store the content using the [Storage API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage). (Although I have heard that you could/should(?) use the [cordova-plugin-android-storage](https://github.com/apache/cordova-labs/tree/plugins/android-storage) in cordova-labs.)

Comment: I'm not really sure what the best way to check that new recipes and/or images are available. Maybe each recipe should have a version number. When a recipe or image in a recipe is changed, the version number is incremented. The app could make sure the version numbers match up. I think this would work for a small set of recipes but you will probably need a different solution for thousands of documents. At that point I would do incremental "updates" that contain say 100 updated recipes, and the user can choose to download it or not.

Comment: Thanks, that helps some. I'm going to have a separate xml file that is just an update file. If it exists I will download the new recipe.xml file, and also any images in the update file.